# Pytest Import Error with Pylenium on a Poetry Virtual Env

Tags: python, pytest, python-poetry

when trying to run Pytest on a virtual env with poetry, I am running into the following error with `Pylenium`, would anybody happen to know what this means?

```
\`
Test\> pytest
ImportError while loading conftest 'conftest.py'.

conftest.py:32: in \<module\>
from pylenium.a11y import PyleniumAxe
......\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\pylenium\__init_\_.py:1: in \<module\>
from .pylenium import \*
......\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\pylenium\\pylenium.py:15: in \<module\>
from . import conditions
......\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\pylenium\\conditions.py:65: in \<module\>
class title_is (Condition, ec.title_is):
E   TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases

\`
```

I have already tried creating a new virtual environment, using an older version of `pylenium`. Any Ideas?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.